# how to stop youtube video playing when container closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube, youtube-api

I have seen a few posts about this , but the answers I find are about 1 video and not multiple videos on same page.

I have around 10 videos on my web page. When we click the button for each I want the overlay to pop up which it does. Then a video to be played.

Once the user clicks the exit button I want the video to stop playing.

At the minute if a user does no click pause of the youtube video and exits out it keeps playing in the background.

i will show just 2 video sections for this example:

```
  <div class="play-button">
      <i class="fa fa-play"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="youtube-frame">
      <div class="exit-youtube-frame">
          <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
      </div>
      <iframe width="520" height="345" src="<?= $video ?>"></iframe>
  </div>


  <div class="play-button">
      <i class="fa fa-play"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="youtube-frame">
      <div class="exit-youtube-frame">
          <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
      </div>
      <iframe width="520" height="345" src="<?= $video ?>"></iframe>
  </div>
```

Now in Jquery i do this:

```
            jQuery('.play-button').click(function(){
                jQuery('#overlay-youtube').show(); // This is the overlay
                jQuery(this).next().show();
            });

            jQuery('.exit-youtube-frame').click(function(){
                jQuery(this).parents('.youtube-frame').hide();
                jQuery('#overlay-youtube').hide();
            });
```

How do i incorporate method which will stop the video playing for each section?

Comment: use a customizable video API like JW player or something

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with showing product videos on a site and stopping them from playing after closing the overlay.

As long as you don't need to pause the video so the user can pick up where they left off, you can simply use the `detach()` method to store the video object in jQuery then re-add it to the DOM when the user clicks to show it.

Here is my code for just one video (HTML then jQuery):

```
<div id="product-video-overlay">
  <div id="video-container">
     <a class="close-overlay">Close</a>
     <iframe id="ytplayeroverlay" type="text/html" src="{youtubeURL}"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>


    var videoOverlay = $('#product-video-overlay');
    var videoObject = videoOverlay.find('#video-container');
    var hasVideo = 1;

    $('li.video-thumb').click(function () {
       if (hasVideo == 0) {
          videoObject.appendTo(videoOverlay);
       }
       videoOverlay.fadeIn();
    });
    $('#product-video-overlay, #product-video-overlay a.close-overlay').click(function (e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
       videoOverlay.fadeOut();
       videoObject.detach();
       hasVideo = 0;
    });
```

Since you have multiple videos, you will need some way to identify the play button with its corresponding overlay/video (maybe adding a matching class to each?).

As well, you would probably want to store each detached element into an array to retrieve later by the matching class or whatever method you use to link the button to the proper video.

This is just how I tackled the problem. I know there is a YouTube API available to use, but this did the job.

Good luck!